# How to show a popup if an image(s) has not fully loaded in a particular timeframe using Owl Carousel-2 (v-2.3.4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using Owl Carousel-2 v2.3.4 which is initialized as follows:

```
$('#myPages').owlCarousel({
        dots: false,
        lazyLoad: true,
        lazyLoadEager: 2,
        autoWidth: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        items: 1,
        slideBy: 1,
        nav: false,
        loop: false,
        checkVisible:false,
        margin: 10,
        onDragged: callback,
        onInitialized: callback1,
        onLoadLazy: checkImgLoad(this),
        //onLoadedLazy: checkImgLoaded
    })
```

In the above initialization, I have added `checkImgLoad` for `onLoadLazy` callback which is basically called when a lazy image is loading and has not fully loaded. The main functionality of this function is to check in a particular time frame (for example 5 seconds) if the image has loaded or not. If the image has not loaded in that 5 second duration, a popup should be shown to the user that image is still being loaded. Once the image has fully loaded, the popup should automatically disappear.

For a better understanding of the callbacks you can refer to their official [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

There is also a `onLoadedLazy` callback which is triggered by the plugin when lazy image has fully loaded so that can also be used if necessary. I thought of putting a `setTimeout` function in the `onLoadLazy` callback function like this:

```
var myVar;
function checkImgLoad(imgObj) {
        try {
         clearTimeout(myVar);
         var imgload=true;
         if (!imgObj.complete || imgObj.naturalWidth === 0) {
            imgload= false;
         }

        if (!imgload) {
            $("#loader").show();
            myVar = setTimeout(function () {
                try {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    var modal = document.getElementById("myPopup");
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
                    document.getElementById("btn_close").onclick = function () {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                } 
                catch (error) { }
            }, 5000); //after every 5 seconds
            
        }
    } catch (error) { }
}
```

But I am having problems in getting the current image object in question (`this` keyword does not work) and overall in getting the gist of the callback's and how to use them to achieve such a functionality. It would be great if someone could help me out or share their knowledge on this scenario.

My HTML structure is below:

```
<div id="myPages">
<div class="mylayer"><img class="img-one owl-lazy" src="myimg1.jpg" data-src="myimg1.jpg" /><img class="img-two owl-lazy" src="myimg1.png" data-src="myimg1.png" />
</div>

<div class="mylayer"><img class="img-one owl-lazy" src="myimg2.jpg" data-src="myimg2.jpg" /><img class="img-two owl-lazy" src="myimg2.png" data-src="myimg2.png" />
</div>

<div class="mylayer"><img class="img-one owl-lazy" src="myimg3.jpg" data-src="myimg3.jpg" /><img class="img-two owl-lazy" src="myimg3.png" data-src="myimg3.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before tackling the problem at hand, you have an issue with the `onLoadLazy` event, that option expects a function (`onLoadLazy: checkImgLoad`), but you are passing a function call to it (`onLoadLazy: checkImgLoad(this)`).

Comment: Did you maybe intend to do: `onLoadLazy: (this) => checkImgLoad(this)`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q3cdgxts/ just an idea of how it could work. (the last image here is a defect one so that triggers the modal after 5 sec.)

Comment: @RolandStarke Thanks for the effort. I wanted to ask you that how will the popup hide automatically when the image has loaded? Also if there are two images in a single frame, I need to find out if both the images have completely loaded otherwise show the slow loading popup. I hope you get my point.

Comment: You can just maintain a array of booleans that's equivalent to the number of images  being loaded. Set the values of each item in the array to true once the image corresponding to that index is loaded, in @RolandStarke example above, its in the img onLoad event. Additionally you'll need to add some logic within the timeout function to only show the popup if any items in the array, indexed corresponding to the current window of the carousel, are false.